# Is atomic failover for single high-throughput servers feasible?

Tags: atomic, failover, distributed-system

I need atomic failover for my current distributed system to work properly. By atomic failover, I mean that at and after some point in time, all requests are served by a new server (or not at all), even in the presence of failures.

I'm handling orders of magnitude more messages than ZooKeeper seems to handle for writes (which seems to be around ~20k/s), and I'm expecting reads with sync to not be much faster than writes, so routing all requests through ZooKeeper doesn't seem to be an option.

All requests must be handled by the same server for performance and correctness reasons; touching a database or communicating between servers for each request is way to slow, so horizontal scaling isn't an option, and having two servers both serving requests in parallel without talking to each other will violate correctness.

Is there a feasible way to get high throughput (1M/s+) atomic failover, even in the presence of failures? Downtime of a few seconds for each failover is fine, normally requests process in a few ms. Dropping requests is also fine, as the clients will retry.

Answer (score 0):

My team's software does thousands of atomic fail-overs per day at high throughput. There is really only one trick to it; and some tricks to improve latencies during the failover.

The key trick is that the system has to have a transactional latch that prevents any more transactions on the old system. That is, the failover is triggered by committing a transaction on the old system such that after it is committed clients get a special error saying that the failover has happened. Everything before that commit is on the old system, everything after is on the new system.

There are are various ways to do this. First, a flag on commit can *seal* the old system entirely, preventing ALL transactions. Or you can take a generational approach where the transactions have a *generation* (aka *epoch*) field. In the generational approach, failing over is just changing the generation of the old system.

To improve latencies, make sure everything is primed to use the new system. The new system should be ready to accept the new generation. If possible right before the failover, the clients/proxies should have connections open to the new system, ready for the old system to say failover has happened, ready to seamlessly transfer the traffic to the new system.

Comment: How does this handle servers that has to be failed over because they're slow? How do you guarantee that no more requests are processed when 90%+ of requests are dropped, and that no currently executing requests are responded to by the old instance?

Comment: If your data is critical enough that you must have only one server processing it (hence atomic failover), then you must also have a mechanism for replicating that data to the secondaries. For more details, we probably need details on that replication protocol, be it Raft or Paxos or whatever. But in the mean time, look at how LMAX did theirs; they claim micro-second failover. [Martin Fowler  mentions it a little](https://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html).